# How do longpoll multiple urls using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, long-polling

The goal is to have multiple longpoll connections open to multiple urls (like `example.com/user/1`, `example.com/user/2`, etc) and when data is updated, process it, and reconnect. Here's a simple example of what I have so far:

```
async function longpoll(url) {
    http.get(url, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (data) => {
            // do something with data
        }
        response.on('end', () => {
            // cleanup
            longpoll(url)
        }
    }
}
```

I've got more going on, but this is the basic setup.  This works for a single url, but if I try to add more, like in a loop, it closes all but one.  Can someone point me in the direction of being able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function startLongPollingForMultipleUrls(urls) {
    urls.forEach(url => longpoll(url);
}

function longpoll(url) {
    http.get(url, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (data) => {
            // do something with data
        }
        response.on('end', () => {
            // cleanup
            // Use a timeout to wait 1 second between calls
            setTimeout(() => longpoll(url), 1000)
        }
    }
}

const myUrls = ['example.com/user/1', 'example.com/user/2']

startLongPollingForMultipleUrls(myUrls);
```